# How to align content inside rows of an <article> vertically with each other

Tags: html, css, flexbox, alignment, article

I am trying to align content inside rows of an article vertically with each other

This is in the card component

`

```
 <div className="user-card">
      <img
        className="avatar"
        src={`/assets/${user.homeTeam}.png`}
        alt={user.homeTeam}
      />
      <img
        className="avatar"
        src={`/assets/${user.awayTeam}.png`}
        alt={user.awayTeam}
      />
      <div className="info">
        <h3>
          {user.homeTeam} vs {user.awayTeam}
        </h3>
        <span style={{ margin: "1em" }}></span>
        <img
          alt=""
          src="/assets/calendar.svg"
          style={{ height: "40px", width: "40px" }}
        />
        <span style={{ margin: "0.5em" }}></span>
        <h3>{user.Date}</h3>
        <span style={{ margin: "1em" }}></span>

        <img
          alt=""
          src="/assets/stadium.svg"
          style={{ height: "40px", width: "40px" }}
        />
        <span style={{ margin: "0.5em" }}></span>
        <h3>{user.location} </h3>
        <span style={{ margin: "1em" }}></span>
        {/* <p>
          Score: {user.homeTeamScore} - {user.awayTeamScore}
        </p> */}
        <button class="button button-green width-auto">Book Ticket</button>
      </div>
    </div>
```

`

App.css

`

```
.App {
  text-align: center;
  width: 95%;
  max-width: 800px;
  margin: 6rem auto 0;
}

.user-container {
  display: grid;
  justify-content: center;
  grid-template-columns: 1fr 1fr;
  gap: 0.5rem;
}
.card-container {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: 1fr 1fr 1fr;
  grid-template-rows: 100px 100px;
}

.button.width-auto {
  width: 130px;
  padding: 0 15px;
  max-width: none;
}
.button.button-green {
  background-color: #219f45;
}
[role="button"],
[type="button"]:not(:disabled),
[type="reset"]:not(:disabled),
[type="submit"]:not(:disabled),
button:not(:disabled) {
  cursor: pointer;
}
.button {
  display: block;
  text-align: center;
  width: 100px;
  max-width: 130px;
  margin: 0;
  height: 45px;
  line-height: 45px;
  color: #fff !important;
  padding: 0;
  border: none;
  cursor: pointer;
  font-size: 14px;
  transition: all 0.1s linear;
  font-family: EncodeSansExpanded-Bold, arial, tahoma;
}
.user-card {
  display: flex;
  padding: 1rem;
  text-align: left;
  margin-left: 1rem;
  margin-bottom: 0.5rem;
  margin: 0 auto; /* Added */
  float: none; /* Added */
  margin-bottom: 10px; /* Added */
  width: 1200px;
  margin: 2em;
  border: 1px solid grey;
  border-radius: 5px;
  cursor: pointer;
  transition: all 0.25s ease;
}
.user-card:hover {
  background-color: #0a0a0a;
}

.avatar {
  display: flex;
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
  border-radius: 50%;
}

.info {
  align-items: center;
  display: flex;
  text-align: left;
  margin-left: 1rem;
}

.info h3,
.info p {
  align-items: center;
  margin-bottom: 0.5rem;
}
div {
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: left;
}
.user-post {
  max-width: 500px;
  width: 95%;
  margin: 0 auto;
}

.user-post h2 {
  margin: 1rem auto;
  color: white;
}

.user-post a {
  cursor: pointer;
  text-decoration: none;
}

.user-card__image {
  display: flex;
}

.user-post a:hover {
  color: #5dd4ac;
}

@media (max-width: 600px) {
  .user-container {
    grid-template-columns: 1fr;
  }
}
```

`

and I am creating cards from my home file inside an article

[image: what I'm getting]

I need every element in the card to be aligned on all rows. I tried placing every element in a div with a class that has display: flex and align-content: left, but no hope

Update:
[image: update]

Comment: Looks like a job for Css-grid

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should first group the elements you want to be together in a `div`. So the country flags + names together, calendar icon + date and time, stadium icon + stadium name and you can leave the button as it is.

Then you should give `.user-card` a `display: grid;` and `grid-template-columns: 2fr 2fr 2fr 1fr;` (depends on what size you want every grid column to be).

Comment: It kinda worked but still not perfectly aligned. I added a new image of the output in the post. Edit: I figured it out.. I had to remove the span tags with the margins in the html. Thank you!